# Given the function $f(x) =xe^{ax}$

Tags: calculus

Show that if $f(x) =xe^{ax}$, where $a>0$, the absolute minimum value of $f$ is $-\frac{1}{a e}$.

I'm unsure how to approach this question. I've tried several things including plugging in the critical point of the first derivative.

Comment: Show us what you found, I can't imagine what you got wrong.

Comment: Setting the first derivative of the equation will yield x= -1/2 as the critical point. Therefore, the absolute extrema of the function occur at that point. However, I'm unsure as to what I am supposed to do to prove that f(x) = Xe when the minimum is −1/ .

Comment: @HarperAvery Is $a=2$? Before I edited it you had $a=2$ in the title, but $a>0$ in the main body of the question.

Comment: It is a several part question. Within the first three parts, a is equal to 2. In the last part it is changed to a variable and asks for a  proof.

Comment: If it is $a$, what do you get as the critical point? What is $f$ at that point?

Comment: If a =2, the critical point is equal to -1/2

Comment: Yes, now try to find the critical point for other $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=xe^{ax}$ with $a>0$. Then, $f'(x)=axe^{ax}+e^{ax}=e^{ax}(1+ax)$ and it follows that the only critical point is at $x=-\frac{1}{a}$ (why?). In particular, $f'(0)>0$ and $f'(-\frac{2}{a})<0$ so this cricital point is at least a local minimum. But note that f is decreasing always to the left of $-\frac{1}{a}$ and increasing always to the right of this point. What does this then imply about the local minimum $x=-\frac{1}{a}$?